# CRD probe failing

Tags: kubernetes

I am installing [service](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/service-catalog) catalog which uses CRD and have created the same. Now I am running my controller deployment file and the image running in it runs a CRD list command to verify CRD are in place. This use to work fine previously but now CRD Probe is failing with error:

```
1226 07:45:01.539118       1 round_trippers.go:438] GET https://169.72.128.1:443/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/customresourcedefinitions?labelSelector=svcat%3Dtrue  in 30000 milliseconds
I1226 07:45:01.539158       1 round_trippers.go:444] Response Headers:
Error: while waiting for ready Service Catalog CRDs: failed to list CustomResourceDefinition: Get https://169.72.128.1:443/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/customresourcedefinitions?labelSelector=svcat%3Dtrue: dial tcp 169.72.128.1:443: i/o timeout
```

I have followed same steps as previously but could not debug now.

Inside the controller code it is trying to make following call:

```
list, err := r.client.ApiextensionsV1beta1().CustomResourceDefinitions().List(v1.ListOptions{LabelSelector: labels.SelectorFromSet(labels.Set{"svcat": "true"}).String()})
```

Which is failing.

Update 1 : Installation works fine in default namespace but fails in specific namespace.

Environment Info: On Prem k8s cluster, latest k8s, 2 node cluster.

Comment: Could you provide more informations about your env? Minikube, Kubeadm, On-Prem, versions of software, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a port issue.Service accounts use 443 port to connect to Kubernetes API Server. Check the if there is any network policy blocking the communication between your namespace and Kube-System namespace.

Comment: health is performed on pod and pod can communicate with itself